# Android app doesn't compile in release with ndk

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm facing an issue to compile my app in release mode. It's a tricky error cause I'm using NDK to use C audio codec for my app.

It's working fine in debug mode, I have no issue but in release It don't want to compile at all and sign an APK if I remove the C part of my app It works.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, It seems to come from the Makefile and the compilation of my C objects.

Thanks for your help ! Any answer could be helpfull ! Tell me if you need anything else.

This is the error and some parts of my code.

> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed
>   :app:externalNativeBuildRelease FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>    What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildRelease'.
>   Build command failed.
>     Error while executing process /Users/lg/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /Users/lg/projects/remi-android-app/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi --target codec-lib}
>     [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/codec-lib.dir/g722_codec.c.o
>     FAILED: /Users/lg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang  --target=armv5te-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/Users/lg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/lg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-18/arch-arm -Dcodec_lib_EXPORTS  -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -Os -DNDEBUG -Os -DNDEBUG  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/codec-lib.dir/g722_codec.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/codec-lib.dir/g722_codec.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/codec-lib.dir/g722_codec.c.o   -c /Users/lg/projects/remi-android-app/app/src/main/jni/g722_codec.c
>     fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: 0x7f7f640d3170: i32 = ARMISD::SSAT 0x7f7f640bf390, Constant:i32<15>
>       0x7f7f640bf390: i32 = shl 0x7f7f640be750, Constant:i32<2>
>         0x7f7f640be750: i32,ch = load%26> 0x7f7f618dfa50, 0x7f7f640d35d0, undef:i32
>           0x7f7f640d35d0: i32 = add 0x7f7f641024a0, Constant:i32<156>
>             0x7f7f641024a0: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x7f7f631625f0, Register:i32 %vreg24
>               0x7f7f64102d60: i32 = Register %vreg24
>             0x7f7f640bef30: i32 = Constant<156>
>           0x7f7f618dff20: i32 = undef
>         0x7f7f6401bbb0: i32 = Constant<2>
>       0x7f7f64102ba0: i32 = Constant<15>
>     In function: block4l_d
>     clang: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
>     Android clang version 3.8.275480  (based on LLVM 3.8.275480)
>     Target: armv5te-none-linux-android
>     Thread model: posix
>     InstalledDir: /Users/lg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin
>     clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
>     clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
>     PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
>     Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
>     clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/07/4hq2_z0n7215k761dp4v49t00000gn/T/g722_codec-38a769.c
>     clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/07/4hq2_z0n7215k761dp4v49t00000gn/T/g722_codec-38a769.sh
>     clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
>     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
>
> ---

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }

  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
}

android {
   signingConfigs {
       configRelease {
           keyAlias 'key0'
           keyPassword '******'
           storeFile file('/Users/lg/projects/app/keys/key.jks')
        storePassword '******'
       }
   }
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.urbanhello"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        jniDebuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.configRelease
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        versionNameSuffix " Debug"
        jniDebuggable true
    }
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```

CMakeList.txt

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.0)
>   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
>   
> add_library( codec-lib
>                SHARED
>                codeclibwrapper.c
>                g722_codec.c)
>   
> find_library(codec-lib
>                 log )
>   
> target_link_libraries(codec-lib
>                         android
>                         log
>                         ${log-lib} )

[App Archi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAnz9.jpg)

Comment: Update NDK and remove any old versions from your system.  Do a clean.  If you still get the error, see if you get it on all ABIs by commenting out and selecting each one.  Also, check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674298/sdl2-sample-build-error-with-android-ndk-r14

Comment: Hello James, nice answer It was caused by ABIs in gradle I'have removed some of them and It's working now, thank you man !

Comment: Yeah, debug builds usually only target a single ABI, and I noticed you had mixed several different ones with different capabilities.

Comment: Did you file a bug like the error message said? You can also file one [here](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues) so we can track it for the NDK.